# Remove unwanted nested elements with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

In my document I have some unwanted nested `<bo>` tags. What would be the easiest way to xslt them away?

Source example:

```
<body>
    <bo>
        <bo>some text</bo>
        <bo>
            <bo>some other text</bo>
        </bo>
        <bo>more text</bo>
    </bo>
  
    <bo>
        <fig/>
    <bo/>
</body>
```

Result example:

```
<body>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some other text</p>
    <p>more text</p>

    <p>
        <fig/>
    <p>
</body>
```

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the following as an approach to build on:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="bo[.//bo]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="boo[not(boo)]">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

If that does not suffice then you need to explain in more detail which input variants you can have and how you want them to be transformed.

A full stylesheet using above templates is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="bo[.//bo]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="boo[not(boo)]">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and transforms

```
<body>
    <bo>
            <bo>some text</bo>
            <bo>
                <bo>some other text</bo>
            </bo>
            <bo>more text</bo>
    </bo>
    <bo>
        <fig/>
    </bo>
</body>
```

into

```
<body>
   <bo>some text</bo>
   <bo>some other text</bo>
   <bo>more text</bo>
   <bo>
      <fig/>
   </bo>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution to omit identical tags nested directly inside each other:

```
<stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <template match="*[name(..)=name()]">
        <apply-templates/>
    </template>

    <template match="@* | node()">
        <copy>
            <apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </copy>
    </template>

</stylesheet>
```

In English: "Copy each node through, unless its name is the same as its parent's; in that case, just copy the children"

Comment: That feels the wrong way round; in the example, it's the parent elements that are dropped, not the children.